# How to use query string in URL to display content on the wordpress page

Tags: urls, parameter, query-string

My wordpress page URL is like this

https:www.com/thanks-page/?origin_name=Sydney&origin_iata=SYD&destination_name=Ahmedabad&destination_iata=AMD

I need to display SYD and AMD in to the page content like this..

Flights from SYD to AMD...

How can I display those two Param query sting in to the actual wordpress page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a WordPress question, this is basic PHP. You can use $_GET for parameters in the url.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple, you can use $_GET method.

```
if(isset($_GET["origin_iata"]) && !empty($_GET["origin_iata"]) && isset($_GET["destination_iata"]) && !empty($_GET["destination_iata"]))
{
       echo "Flights from ".$_GET["origin_iata"]." to ".$_GET["destination_iata"]."...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use `$_GET["origin_iata"]` and `$_GET["destination_iata"]` to get those two Params you need